Circular Image in SwiftUI Menu
Every time I put an Image as Menu content in SwiftUI, I am unable to round its edges or clip its shape. I'd like my displayed image to be the shape of a circle.
Of course, I've tried .cornerRadius() and .clipShape(Circle()). Minimal example:
Menu("Ben") {
  Toggle(isOn: .constant(true)) {
    Label {
      Text("Ben")
    } icon: {
      Image("blueGradient")
        .resizable()
        .clipShape(Circle())
    }
  }
}



You should mask the image before using it as an Image.

If you don't want to add round versions of the images to your asset catalog then you could always convert them to round images on the fly. The Image initializer that uses drawing instructions makes this possible:
let roundImageSize: CGFloat = 72

private func roundImage(name: String) -> Image {
    let size = CGSize(width: roundImageSize, height: roundImageSize)
    return Image(size: size) { ctx in
        let sourceImage = Image(name)
        let resolvedImage = ctx.resolve(sourceImage)
        ctx.clip(to: Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)))
        ctx.draw(resolvedImage, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    }
}

var body: some View {
    Menu("Ben") {
        Toggle(isOn: .constant(true)) {
            Label {
                Text("Ben")
            } icon: {
                roundImage(name: "blueGradient")
            }
        }
    }
}



OK, this seems to work in iOS 16. For previous versions of iOS, it seems I could mess with the underlying UIImage to achieve a similar effect, following @Mojtaba Hosseini's suggestion.

Unfortunately, menu does not accept any view as expected in its API, so you should mask the image before using it as an Image.
You can get help from UIImage with a simple extension like this:
extension UIImage {
    var rounded: UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        let bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: size.height/2.0).addClip()
        draw(in: bounds)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}

And then use it like:
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "blueGradient").rounded!)

You can also use the renderer argument of the native SwiftUI Image initializer to achieve the same if you are targeting iOS 16 or higher.
